# Skin detection in the CIELab and HSV color space

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, hsv

I've seen CIELab and HSV suggested a few times here on stackoverflow, but I haven't been able to find any values corresponding to skin.  What are good values to look for when doing skin detection in the CIELab and HSV color spaces?

For example in RGB I've seen this:

```
R > 95 AND G > 40 AND B > 20 AND
max{R, G, B} – min{R, G, B} >15 AND
|R – G| > 15 AND
R > G AND R > B
OR
R > 220 AND G > 210 AND B > 170 AND
|R – G| <= 15 AND
R > B AND G > B
```

Are there similar expressions for CIELab and HSV?

Answer (score 4):

You could just measure it

Now if there was only a large set of images with large areas of flesh tones available on the internet?

Comment: I need a slashdot style +1-funny for this.

Comment: I actually was thinking to measure it by using some large image collection. But I am researcher and my thinking is to measure everything by myself.

Comment: @Ross - an interesting result is that in the colour space, skin tones are very similar - whatever 'colour' people are

Comment: Yes, i read this somewhere. Color based method should be only the first step, followed by other methods for good skin detection.

Answer (score 3):

Some of my bookmarks on the subject:

[Human Body Tracking by Adaptive
Background Models and Mean-Shift
Analysis](http://www.merl.com/reports/docs/TR2003-036.pdf)

[Adaptive Skin Color Classificator](http://www.icgst.com/GVIP05/papers/P1150535201.pdf)

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/face_detection.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/RedMatterLibrary.aspx

Comment: +1 from these links I went to google scholar articles to see the exact papers they copied their formulas from. This one in particular seems interesting as they have a visual representation of the formulas as well [human face detection](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=tr&q=RGB-H-CbCr+Skin+Colour+Model+for+Human+Face+Detection&btnG=&lr=)