# OpenCV skin detection color space?

Tags: c++, image, video, opencv

I am using histogram backprojection on an HSV image to detect skin.

What would you recommend as the best type of image to use for skin detection? (for the best and most accurate detection) HSV, RGB or YCbCr?

what are the advantages and disadvantages of each type of image and which one would you consider to be the most appropriate for this specific situation?

PS: Due to how my program is made, lighting is not THAT important

Comment: HSV - for reasons see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411369/skin-detection-in-the-cielab-and-hsv-color-space

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at Google Scholar results for [skin detection](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=skin%20detection&hl=en&btnG=Search&as_sdt=1,1&as_sdtp=on). There are several good papers about how you might go about detecting skin.

[This](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.101.1046&rep=rep1&type=pdf) paper is a good survey. Also, [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.8.6612&rep=rep1&type=pdf) paper discusses optimal color spaces for skin detection. The paper also argues that all color spaces provide the same amount of information, but that some color spaces are more intuitive than others for skin detection.

Hope that's helpful!